# How to extract a specific month and day from all the years in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, time-series

My dataset looks like this

```
            CPI
DATE    
1950-01-01  NaN
1950-02-01  1.004254
1950-03-01  1.005530
1950-04-01  1.005955
1950-05-01  1.011059
... ...
2020-01-01  1.001455
2020-02-01  1.002345
2020-03-01  0.998100
2020-04-01  0.990164
2020-05-01  0.989646
```

I would like to extract all the data from 'XXXX-01-01' in every year. And put them into a new data set. Could anyone make an example how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
new_df = df.loc[(df.DATE.dt.month == 1) & (df.DATE.dt.day == 1)]
```

Comment: Sorry, I am a total newbie in Pandas, i tried your method, it shows an error ''DataFrame' object has no attribute 'DATE''

Comment: @Flyingpig: since DATE is the index of the DataFrame, you have to call `new_df = df.loc[(df.index.month == 1) & (df.index.day == 1)]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) also

```py
df.query("index.dt.month.eq(1) and index.dt.day.eq(1)")
```

Assuming you have index of `Datetimeindex` type if not first convert it `Datetimeindex` using
`df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)`